# Simplifying equation with composite function

Tags: functions

Given this function f(x) = x - 1/x , i'm trying to solve f(f(f.....(f(x))))) = x

is it possible to derive the solutions for a higher number of composition using a reccurrence formula ?

for example : from the solutions of f(f(f(x)))=x we can derive solutions  f(f(f(f(f(x))))=x   ....

The only thing that  i noticed is that The function is odd

Comment: Just to be clear, is "f(f(f.....(f(x))))) = x" supposed to represent that $x =$ the result of *infinite composition*?

Comment: I could not find a closed form, but you can study the map $x_{n+1}=x_n-1/x_n$ by a simple calculation on Excel. Doing that I only noticed unstable bahavior. The function $x-1/x$ has 2 symmetric branches for positive and negative $x$. If I started with some positive $x_0$ I noticed that after some iterations the it gets negative and reaches  some maximal negative value $x_{m1}$ with  $|x_{m1}|>x_0$ .  It then reverses and becasue of symmetry gets to maximal positive value $x_{m2}$ such that $x_{m2}>|x_{m1}|$. Thus its seems that it oscillates with increasing maximal values.

Comment: "f(f(f.....(f(x))))) = x " supposed to represent big number of composition , for example 50